# Пропадает таблица в базе данных duckDB

Tags: java, jdbc

Использую базу данных duckDB для чтения файлов parquet.
Подключаю ее следующим образом:

```
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource){
        JdbcTemplate duckdb =new JdbcTemplate();
        duckdb.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return duckdb;
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName("org.duckdb.DuckDBDriver");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        config.setMaxLifetime(3);
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:duckdb:");
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return ds;
    }
```

И выполняю запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT * FROM 'test.parquet';
```

Потом получаю данные из таблицы, произвожу вычисления и сохраняю в таблицу.
Вся работа должна длится более часа.
Но через пол часа код останавливается с сообщением о том, что таблицы test не существует.
Может кто знает в чем проблема?